# Create an array with a sequence of numbers in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to write a script that will create me an array with the following values:

```
{0.1 0.2 0.3 ... 2.5}
```

Until now I was using a script as follows:

```
plist=(0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4)
for i in ${plist[@]}; do
    echo "submit a simulation with this parameter:"
    echo "$i"
done
```

But now I need the list to be much longer ( but still with constant intervals).

Is there a way to create such an array in a single command? what is the most efficient way to create such a list?

Comment: if the interval is constant, why not make a function that takes the index and returns the value by computing it?

Comment: Tray `seq` command if the interval is constant.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Using [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) you can say `seq FIRST STEP LAST`. In your case:

```
seq 0 0.1 2.5
```

Then it is a matter of storing these values in an array:

```
vals=($(seq 0 0.1 2.5))
```

You can then check the values with:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${vals[@]}"
0,0
0,1
0,2
...
2,3
2,4
2,5
```

Yes, my locale is set to have commas instead of dots for decimals. This can be changed setting `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`.

By the way, [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) also allows to set an increment. The problem is that it has to be an integer:

```
$ echo {0..15..3}
0 3 6 9 12 15
```

Answer (score 10):

Bash supports C style For loops:

```
$ for ((i=1;i<5;i+=1)); do echo "0.${i}" ; done
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
```

Comment: This does not create an array, so not relevant to the question

Comment: `array=($(for ((i=1;i<5;i+=1)); do echo "0.${i}"; done))`

Answer (score 1):

### Complementing the main answer

In my case, `seq` was not the best choice.
To produce a sequence, you can also use the `jot` utility. However, this command has a more elaborated syntaxis.

```sh
# 1 2 3 4
jot - 1 4

# 3 evenly distributed numbers between 0 and 10
# 0 5 10
jot 3 0 10

# a b c ... z
jot -c - 97 122
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `jot` is better than `seq` in some cases?